# Titan: has() doesn't work

Tags: titan, gremlin

I have been trying to query my graph using this query

```
graph()
   .traversal()
   .V()
   .has(Tokens.FIRSTNAME)
   .filter(vt ->
        vt.get().property(Tokens.FIRSTNAME).equals("Hank")
   );
```

And that always return no result. When I debugged the code, I noticed that the comparison happens at `AbstractElement#equals()` and it returns false because the passed value (String) is not `Vertex` or `Edge` or `VertexProperty`

Another way to do the same thing but never works too is

```
graph()
    .traversal()
    .V()
    .has(Tokens.FIRSTNAME, "Hank")
```

I'm using titan `0.9.0-M2`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Titan 1.0.0 is now available at http://titandb.io and you should be using that instead of 0.9.0-M2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query should be:

```
graph()
   .traversal()
   .V()
   .has(Tokens.FIRSTNAME)
   .filter(vt ->
        vt.get().value(Tokens.FIRSTNAME).equals("Hank")
   );
```

Or even better:

```
graph()
   .traversal()
   .V()
   .has(Tokens.FIRSTNAME, "Hank")
```

Comment: Adding to Daniel's response, keep in mind that the best practice is to use the defined steps like `has()` instead of the lambda steps like `filter()`. Read more about it here http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#lambda-steps